# preg_split and multiple patterns

Tags: php, regex

I have following bit of php code using regular expressions:

```
$result_from_pull = "T601092";

if(preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9]{2,6}[0-9]{1,3}$/", $result_from_pull)) {
    echo "We found a \"valid\" UFS key.";
}
```

What I'm trying to do is split the string into two parts. The first part would match the beginning of the pattern, `[A-Za-z0-9]{2,6}`, while the second part would match the tail end of the pattern, `[0-9]{1,3}`.

How do I use preg_split to accomplish this? Can it be done on one preg_split or should I be using two or another function altogether?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) you can achieve this using a reluctant quantifier with your `{n,m}` repetition, the [`\K`](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#k) escape sequence and a [Positive Lookahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookaround).

```
$results = preg_split('/^[a-z0-9]{2,6}?\K(?=[0-9]{1,3}$)/i', $string);
print_r($results);
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yC9aH9/13) ( or see a [working demo](http://ideone.com/psjSXd) )

Comment: It works but not well as intended. The right results would be `[0] => T601` and `[1] => as 092` Which I get but it requires a bit more work.

Comment: Actually I found out a way to get it to work that way. (I'm going to have to check part one against an array.) Although my print_r is returning three parts and not two for some reason..

Comment: Good use of `\K` I love it.

Comment: Oh wait... NOW I see what's going on, this is using preg_split, I was still using preg_match.

Answer (score 3):

`preg_split` is the wrong function for this. Use capture groups.

```
if(preg_match("/^([A-Za-z0-9]{2,6})([0-9]{1,3})$/", $result_from_pull, $matches)) {
    echo "We found a \"valid\" UFS key.";
    var_dump($matches);
    // you should see the first part in $matches[1], and the second in $matches[2]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Get the matched group from index 1 and 2

```
^([A-Za-z0-9]{2,6})([0-9]{1,3})$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nO7jF9/4)

sample code:

```
$re = "/^([A-Za-z0-9]{2,6})([0-9]{1,3})$/";
$str = "T601092";

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
```